# Injection "settings" not found. Vue composition API provide and inject issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to pass a reactive object using vues provide and inject and I get the `[Vue warn]: injection "settings" not found.` warning and when I log out settings it returns as undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

I made a quick little [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-currying-d4ojnj?file=/src/App.vue) to replicate the issue.

If anyone has any ideas why this is happening please let me know!

Cheers!

**Test.vue**

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, provide, reactive } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const settings = reactive({
      theme: "light",
      color: "#F092AD",
      id: 69,
    });
    provide("settings", settings);
    return {};
  },
});
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <pre>{{ settings }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, inject } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const settings = inject("settings");
    console.log(`settings → `, settings);
    return { settings };
  },
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use provide function to provide data to a component's descendants.

In your case component is not descendant so you get warning because nothing is provided.

You can ether use app level provide like:

```
app.provide(/* key */ 'message', /* value */ 'hello!')
```

or some global state management tool like pinia or vuex.

Take a look at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-sun-3odqjo) or snippet:

```js
const { reactive, provide, inject } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const msg = inject("message");
    const settings = reactive({
      theme: "light",
      color: "#F092AD",
      id: 69,
    });
    provide("settings", settings);
    return { msg };
  },
})
app.component('child', {
  template: `<pre><test /></pre>`,
})
app.component('test', {
  template: `<pre>{{ settings }}</pre>`,
  setup() {
    const settings = inject("settings");
    return { settings };
  },
})
app.provide(/* key */ "message", /* value */ "hello!");
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <pre>{{ msg }}</pre>
  <child />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the codesandbox doesnt seem to work either on my end:l

Comment: It's working , just give it time to load, or refresh. My point was, you can only use provide/inject from loaded component to all children. Your component isn't loaded that's why you get warning. You can ether use app level provide or some global state management tool like pinia or vuex.

Comment: I should've put in my post that I am not using global state at all in this project, so that's why I was reaching for provide/inject. Thanks again for all the help Nikola!